# Unicode characters cannot be displayed on Chrome tab title on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, linux-mint

After doing an apt-get dist-upgrade, unicode characters including Chinese and Japanese cannot be displayed in Chrome's tab titles. They are correctly displayed elsewhere (e.g. page content, bookmarks, etc.)

I have already tried

```
1. apt-get purge google-chrome-stable and reinstall
2. create new profile in chrome
3. rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Chrome Version:32.0.1700.77 (Official Build 244503)

Operating System: Linux Mint 13 Maya

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and the following worked for me:

1. Go to `/etc/fonts/conf.d`
2. Backup then remove any of the *.conf entries for the Google Droid font (in my case `59- droid-serif-fonts.conf 60-droid-sans-mono-fonts.conf 65-droid-sans-fonts.conf`)
3. Update fontconfig `fc-cache -f -r`

Your problem should now be fixed :-D

Comment: Worked like a charm! Mind telling me how you figured this out?

Comment: I found the solution in this discussion: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=316723

Answer (score 0):

I installed `ttf-ancient-fonts` from the Ubuntu Package Center and that provided me the necessary unicode fonts.